# Exception to handle while working with Entity Framework 6

Tags: exception, entity-framework-6

I am working with Entity Framework (v.6) database first in my app. Currently my `try..catch` is as follows -

```
        try
        {



        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
```

Is there any other exception type for entity framework that I should catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {

          }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex) { 

         }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex) {

         }
        catch (SqlException ex) { 

         }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
```